# How can I pass multiple radio button value as a Parameter?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have the following code to display `IList<string>` array in radio button. How can I pass prior month/s?

In My view i have the following code, currently I only display the selected radio button value

```
foreach (var record in Model.Months.Select(x=>$"{x.Substring(4,2)}/{x.Substring(0,4)}").OrderByDescending(x=>x))
{
     <div class="radio col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5" style="">
            @Html.RadioButton("MonthsAvailable", record, true, new { id = record, @class = "m-r" })<label>@record</label>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
}
```

My Model looks like as follows

```
public class MonthsAvailable
 {
        public List<string> Months{ get; set; }       
 }
```

My action receives

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MonthsAvailable(List<string> monthsAvailable)
 {
 ...
 }
```

My radio button looks like as follows

```
When I select 062020 pass only 062020 to the controller, 
When I select 072020 pass 062020 and 072020, 
when I select 082020 pass 062020, 072020 and  082020
when I select 092020 pass 062020, 072020, 082020 and 092020 and etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a LinkedList<> instead of List<> ?

Linked list will give you access to elements prior to or after the one selected.
Check the Microsoft documents on the usage:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=net-5.0

Comment: you mean in the model?

Comment: @kukamuk no not the model, I mean your async task. or create a whole new method to try and process the linked list

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to pass the whole array. Enough to pass selected data. Inside of the action you can calculate what fields do you need.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MonthsAvailable(string monthAvailable)
 {
 ....
 }
```